# Alternating between sorting in ascending and descending order on a button click

Tags: swift

i would like to resort my table.
i have this code part:

```
func ReSort() {
   CoreDataItems.sortInPlace({$0.RowName< $1.RowName})
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This function will call after pressing a button.
but how can i solve this, that if i press the button the first time, the sort function will sort it like this way:

```
$0.RowName < $1.RowName
```

and the second time like this:

```
$0.RowName > $1.RowName
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the current state of the sort in an instance variable, e.g.

```
var sortAscending : Bool = true
```

Now you can do this:

```
func ReSort() {
   CoreDataItems.sortInPlace({sortAscending ? $0.RowName < $1.RowName : $0.RowName > $1.RowName})
   sortAscending = !sortAscending
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The value of `sortAscending` will select between `>` and `<` in the comparison. The assignment

```
sortAscending = !sortAscending
```

done after the sorting will alternate between `true` and `false`.

A shorter but slightly less readable code that has the same effect uses `==` operator as a replacement for inverted `XOR` on `Bool` values:

```
func ReSort() {
   CoreDataItems.sortInPlace({sortAscending == ($0.RowName < $1.RowName) })
   sortAscending = !sortAscending
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine :) is there an way to use variable insteads of the the constant RowName?

Comment: @Stack108 You are welcome! I saw your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36710670/335858), so I assume you know the answer.