# Reorder dynamic UITableView by NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdate

In my app I have a UITableView which will be fill with core date items.

As you can see in this post, I have already asked for a sorting function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36703648/6012187

```
func ReSort() {
   CoreDataItems.sortInPlace({sortAscending ? $0.RowName < $1.RowName : $0.RowName > $1.RowName})
   sortAscending = !sortAscending
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now my question is, how can I set dynamically the RowName Value?
for example. I save the the RowName in the user defaults.

but `$0.defaults.objectForKey("xx")` doesn't work without syntax error

Next question is:

How can I sort with a row, which value is a NSDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort NSArray which contains NSDate by using this code:

```
// objective-c code
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDateTime" 
                                         ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedEventArray = [nodeEventArray
 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

//swift code
let dateDescriptor :NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDateTime", ascending: true)
let sortdescriptors: NSArray = [dateDescriptor]
let sortedeventarray = nodeEventArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([dateDescriptor])
```

After sorting is done, you can reload your tableview

Comment: there is no NSArray, - CoreDataItems is a NSManagedObject. i also need a swift solution please :)

Comment: and where do you sort my CoreDataItems value in your code part. with this code i have to request the data new from core data, isn't it?

Comment: you can get nsmanagedobjects from coredata in the form of array.